# Plot zoom and locator in RStudio

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, interactive

Is there a way to enable `locator()` functionality in the RStudio plot zoom? This only works in the smaller window (default bottom right) of RStudio but when you click on a viewer already open as a separate window, no coordinates are captured:

```
plot(iris$Petal.Width, iris$Petal.Length)
locator()
```

Perhaps the answer here is that is not currently implemented and that is why I couldn't find mention of it online.

I'm using RStudio version 0.99.491.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it works with x11 : `x11(); plot(1:4); locator(1)` what os are you using? I assume windows since the answer below would be irrelevant if you were not using windows.. also works with `quartz(); plot(1:4); locator(1)`. quartz works flawlessly with n given or missing. x11 seems finicky with n missing but doesnt crash if you are patient on the escape

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly use RStudio's "Zoom" function, but gets pretty close at what you're probably after:

```
df <- data.frame(1:4)
windows()
plot(df)
locator(1)
```

A couple of notes:

1. You can't dynamically resize the window. If you want to zoom in, you first need to call `windows()`, then resize the window, then execute `plot(df)`.
2. Be careful to specify the `n` argument for `locator()`. Otherwise it will crash your R session because of [this bug.](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204278968-RStudio-0-99-442-handles-interrupts-from-locator-very-poorly-) (Which hasn't been resolved AFAIK)

But if your purpose is to be able to use `locator()` on a zoomed version of a plot (i.e. if you have a very crowded plot), this should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry. The whole crash R studio session is a bit of deal breaker here.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. It's annoying. Maybe file an issue with RStudio or contact their support that this bug is still exists and needs to be fixed.

Comment: This is insofar a pretty relevant bug, given that together with the `zoom()` package you would be able to combine `zm()` and `locator()` and create a pretty effective instrument to visually picking out individual data points. But since `zoom()` essentially creates another `windows()` instance, this also leads to a session crash (at least on my machine). But maybe this functionality will be added to the `manipulate()`package in the future. Anyway, I think it's a good question.

Comment: In 2021 on my M1 macbook air when I specify `locator(n=5)` it always crashes, but when I just run `locator()` it works. So the opposite of what used to be the case it seems like...